# Hibernate is not working with Spring MVC framework

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to learning Spring MVC with Hibernate. For that I am trying to add a form value into mysql table but having error. I have no idea how to make it work. I have googled for it but can't get it for my work. Can anybody please help me on this please ?!!! here are my attempts below ::

my hibernate.cfg.xml under WEB-INF/classes folder >>>

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springhibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="com.springMVCHibernate.dt.RegistrationDT" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml under WEB-INF folder >>>

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.springMVCHibernate.dao,com.springMVCHibernate.dt,
                                        com.springMVCHibrernate.controllers" /> 

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

 <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

 <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages"/>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

my web.xml under WEB-INF folder >>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">

  <display-name>springmvchibernate</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet   <!--  front controller -->
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my add method in controller where I am trying to save value to database >>>

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registration/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("registrationDT") RegistrationDT registrationDT){

    RegistrationDAO registrationDAO = new RegistrationDAO();
    registrationDAO.addRegistration(registrationDT);

    System.out.println("Saved Successfully.");
}
```

my RegistrationDAO >>>

```
    public class RegistrationDAO implements IRegistrationDAO {

 RegistrationDT registrationDT = null;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void addRegistration(RegistrationDT registrationDT){
        sessionFactory = new Configuration()
        .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
        .buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
               session.saveOrUpdate(registrationDT);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
      }

}
```

my IRegistrationDAO >>>

```
 public interface IRegistrationDAO {

      public void addRegistration(RegistrationDT registrationDT);

}
```

And after submitting form value I am having this error >>>

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Can anybody please help ???

**Full Stack Trace ** - as required >>>

```
    Sep 19, 2015 4:22:02 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
ERROR: HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springhibernate
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1741)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1779)
    at com.springMVCHibernate.dao.RegistrationDAO.addRegistration(RegistrationDAO.java:19)
    at com.springMVCHibrernate.controllers.RegistrationController.submitAdmissionForm(RegistrationController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 19, 2015 4:22:02 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Sep 19, 2015 4:22:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
Sep 19, 2015 4:22:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springhibernate
Sep 19, 2015 4:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/springmvchibernate] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springhibernate
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
    at com.springMVCHibernate.dao.RegistrationDAO.addRegistration(RegistrationDAO.java:22)
    at com.springMVCHibrernate.controllers.RegistrationController.submitAdmissionForm(RegistrationController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? It's hard to know where the exception occurs.

Comment: @Koby hey koby, I have upload full stack trace. I think that will help you

Comment: Seems you are missing MySQL driver jar. Are you using Maven or something alike?

Comment: no I am not using maven. and I have put my mysql-connector.jar in web-inf/classes folder also in lib folder

Comment: Where did you take the jar file from? Does it include com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class?

Comment: Just noticed that you might be placing the file in the wrong folder. Jars should be placed under WEB-INF/lib and not WEB-INF/classes/lib. For more details see here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch06_02.htm

Comment: How do you run the war file? Are you using an IDE or deploying it manually to a container?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to ensure in at least one of following:

1. If you're running your WAR file in servlet container - you can place
   your driver into container's lib folder.
2. Driver (mysql-connector) is in WEB-INF/lib folder inside your WAR file.

If you're running with your IDE - ensure, that mysql-connector is added to your classpath. Way to do it depends on IDE.